# Adding ternary operator in ng-route otherwise condition

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I want to add one ternary condition to otherwise in ng-route. please find below:

```
otherwise({
    redirectTo: $window.location.pathname === '/flight/' || '/air/' ? '/air' : '/hotel'
         });
```

but unfortunatley if i type something in url then it always goes to '/air'.

is there something wrong with above code?

Comment: Wait, why redirect `/air` to `/air`? Sounds like a circular redirection issue

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is set up in a way that it will always resolve to `'/air/'` regardless of what `$window.location.pathname` is.

I think you were likely intending to do this instead:

```
$window.location.pathname === '/flight/' || $window.location.pathname === '/air/' ? '/air' : '/hotel'
```

Comment: it works thanks. how do we write unit test for the below code using jasmine:


`otherwise({redirectTo:function(){
                if(CONTEXTUAL_START_VIEW) {
                    return ($window.location.href.indexOf('/flight/') || $window.location.href.indexOf('/air/')) > -1  ? '/air' : '/hotel';
                }
                else {
                    return '/hotel';
                }
            }});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the expression is only evaluated once.

Make `redirectTo` a function so it is called each time...

```
redirectTo: function(routeParams, currentPath) {
    console.log('Otherwise rule matched for path', currentPath);
    return /^\/(flight|air)\/?$/.test(currentPath) ? '/air' : '/hotel';
}
```

Comment: Try some debugging (see `console.log()` call above)